Thread-safe read from a fastly growing list?
Let's say, we have one list shared across two Python processes:

a data logger process, which fastly appends (immutable) objects to the list, and
a collector process, which occasionally reads the currently available list for further processing.

How would I make that construct smoothly running and thread-safe? Ideally, I would like the list to keep growing during a collect process and just collect the elements that have been available so far. As list.append is atomic (see Python3/FAQ), I fear doing something like on collect
def collect(shared_list):
    # see how many elements safely exist
    initial_length = len(shared_list)
    # and copy those for further processing
    # (even if the list has grown/is growing in the meanwhile)
    collected_list = shared_list[:initial_length]

may lock the shared_list from new appends for too long. I would love to just let it grow in the meanwhile, but in that case the list could be reorganized in memory when running out of allocated memory.
Of course, we do not have to stay with the native list if any other data structure is more appropriate for this use case.

Does the "collector" remove items from the list? If it does, then maybe a queue would be a better pattern. After all, you probably don't want a list that's going to grow ad infinitum

@SIGHUP Great thoughts! In fact, I slightly oversimplified the situation: Currently, so far I didn't limit the grow of the list as the processing looks (almost) arbitrarily back to the past and as I have sufficient control over the overall runtime. However, I do not copy all the data on each collect - that would easily become ugly.

@SIGHUP Thanks to your proposal, I think I should better separate the shared data and the processed data. A queue could be the shared data buffer. The collect-and-process process migrates the fresh queue content to a non-shared list that can be used and managed (e.g., cleaned up in history if I want to introduce this at some point) without interference with the logger process.
